# how to Hide button tooltiptext property in vb.net moving from one form to another form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a button in my form named as Submit and i have set the tooltiptext property of this button to "Submit". When a user moves the cursor over the submit button it shows the tooltiptext and when i click on the button after the tooltiptext remains displayed in the form. Please provide a solution to hide the tooltiptext when user once click on submit button.

thanks in advance

Comment: Move cursor outside of the button control

Comment: A tooltip will remain while hovering over the button. You could is you wish set the tooltip text to an empty string in the button click event... although I have not tried this.

Comment: i have tried to set tooltiptext to empty but its not working

Answer (score -1):

Setting empty string to tooltiptext is not a solution at all.
Windows system should do it by itself - I mean should ensure redrawing all application region - then non used windows/tooltips should disappear. It is normal procedure that screen is redrawn many times per second. If the tooltip stucks on the screen something other is wrong - not tooltip - it just works in normal manner.

Maybe in your function when the Submit's Click event is handled you do something with GDI's methods to prevent automaticaly redrawing?

You can also check out restarting the dwm.exe /using the task manager to kill "dwm.exe" (it restarts automatically) / it can help.

Some piece of code in your handler function would be helpful.

Comment: I did restarting of dwm.exe but that didnt work but instead of close if we use dispose method  it works.

Comment: even dispose is failing in some situation